# Scraper with BS4 does not give back any response (data) on the screen

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to have a overiew on the data of austrian hospitals: how to scrape the data from the site:  https://www.klinikguide.at/oesterreichs-kliniken/

my approach - with BS4 is these few lines. Note: at the moment i want to give the data out on the screen. For the further process the data or save it to a file, database, etc.
but at the mmoent i only want to print out the data on the screen.

well - on colab I get no (!) response.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the website
url = "https://www.klinikguide.at/oesterreichs-kliniken/"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find the elements containing the hospital data
    hospital_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='your-hospital-data-class')

    # Process and print the data
    for hospital in hospital_elements:
        # Extract relevant information (adjust based on the structure of the website)
        hospital_name = hospital.find('span', class_='hospital-name').text
        address = hospital.find('span', class_='address').text
        # Extract other relevant information as needed

        # Print or store the extracted data
        print(f"Hospital Name: {hospital_name}")
        print(f"Address: {address}")
        print("")

    # You can further process the data or save it to a file, database, etc.

else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve the page. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

hospital_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='your-hospital-data-class')
hospital_name = hospital.find('span', class_='hospital-name').text

**update**: note: i changed the code to this

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "https://www.klinikguide.at/oesterreichs-kliniken/"
response = urlopen(url)
html_content = response.read()

soup = BS(html_content, "html.parser")

pat_kontakt = (
    r"(?P<address>.+),\s*"
    r"Tel:\s*(?P<tel>.+),\s*"
    r"E-Mail:\s*(?P<email>.+),\s*"
    r"Webadresse:\s*"
    r"(?P<web_adress>.+)"
)

out = {}

for tag in soup.select(".hospitals a,h2"):
    if tag.name == "h2":
        category = tag.get_text()
    elif tag.name == "a":
        hospital_name = tag.get_text()
        hospital_url = tag["href"]
        with urlopen(hospital_url) as hospital_response:
            hospital_html_content = hospital_response.read()
        soup_kontakt = BS(hospital_html_content, "html.parser")
        m = re.search(pat_kontakt, soup_kontakt.select_one(".kontakt_hospital > p").get_text())
        out.setdefault(category, []).append(dict(name=hospital_name, **m.groupdict()))

        # print(f"{category:<20}", hospital_name) # uncomment if needed

        # import time; time.sleep(2)  # You might want to include a delay to be respectful when scraping

# Now 'out' contains the scraped data
print(out)
```

and get back the following error

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-faa3c9672b73> in <cell line: 21>()
     29         soup_kontakt = BS(hospital_html_content, "html.parser")
     30         m = re.search(pat_kontakt, soup_kontakt.select_one(".kontakt_hospital > p").get_text())
---> 31         out.setdefault(category, []).append(dict(name=hospital_name, **m.groupdict()))
     32 
     33         # print(f"{category:<20}", hospital_name) # uncomment if needed

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

Comment: The info you are searching for is not available under the url you try to scrape, you have to follow each hospital link, also check your `soup` that classes or elements you are searching for exists - You do not get any output, becuase your selections is empty and the loop never starts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are following a tutorial of some sort and you need to find the actual class name of the div element containing the hospital's data.

So you need to change this line:

```py
hospital_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='your-hospital-data-class')
```

To the class name, you find when you "inspect" the web page.

you will also need to change this line to correspond to the actual class name

```py
hospital_name = hospital.find('span', class_='hospital-name').text
```

Comment: hi there  many thanks  i am not so familar with bs4 - but i am very very happy for the answer and for your hints. Awesme. i am very very glad.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The first line of code gives an empty list and the second one throws a `TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments`. @omercotkd, [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: hi there - many thanks for sharing your idea and for adding your thoughts. Well - i think that i have to look after the code - and i am trying to correct the corresponding lines.

Comment: @Timeless I didn't use AI to write this answer... I simply hinted where are the problems in his code, no answer was provided so that's why the first line returned an empty list, if I wanted to I could have just provided a solution but this way the OP would not learn IMO.

Comment: So it means @thannen have most likely used AI to generate the code they share in the original post.

Comment: It's very likely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you came up with the *tag/class* names but you can try the code below.

Also, as stated by @*HedgeHog*, to get the contact information, you need to make another req :

```
import re

pat_kontakt = (
    r"(?P<address>.+),\s*"
    r"Tel:\s*(?P<tel>.+),\s*"
    r"E-Mail:\s*(?P<email>.+),\s*"
    r"Webadresse:\s*(?P<web_adress>.+)"
) # comment some info if they're not needed

out = {}

for tag in soup.select(".hospitals a,h2"):
    if tag.name == "h2":
        category = tag.get_text()
    elif tag.name == "a":
        hospital_name = tag.get_text()
        soup_kontakt = BS(requests.get(tag["href"]).text, "html.parser")
        m = re.search(pat_kontakt, soup_kontakt.select_one(".kontakt_hospital > p").get_text())
        out.setdefault(category, []).append(dict(name=hospital_name, **m.groupdict()))

        # print(f"{category:<20}", hospital_name) # uncomment if needed

    #import time;time.sleep(2) # might be necessary
```

Output :

```
import json; print(json.dumps(out, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))

{
    "Wien": [
        {
            "name": "ATOMOS Klinik Währing",
            "address": "Kreuzgasse 17-19, 1180, Wien",
            "tel": "+43 1 261 66-0",
            "email": "kontakt@ak-waehring.at",
            "web_adress": "https://atomos-klinik-waehring.at/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Evangelisches Krankenhaus",
            "address": "Kreuzgasse 17-19, 1180, Wien",
            "tel": "+43 1 261 66-0",
            "email": "kontakt@ak-waehring.at",
            "web_adress": "https://atomos-klinik-waehring.at/"
        },
        # ...
    ],
    # ...
    "Niederösterreich": [
        {
            "name": "Landesklinikum Allentsteig",
            "address": "Kreuzgasse 17-19, 1180, Wien",
            "tel": "+43 1 261 66-0",
            "email": "kontakt@ak-waehring.at",
            "web_adress": "https://atomos-klinik-waehring.at/"
        }
        # ...
    ],
    # ...
}
```

Comment: hi there   - many thanks for the hint!!! Awesome!

Comment: You're welcome. It's not a hint but a solution to your problem. Can you test it ?

Comment: hi dear Timeless - many many thanks: i am musing about the option to save all the data in a file

Comment: If you show how should look like the data in the file, I think we can help.

Comment: dear Timeless - i am going to test it on Colab now. - i will come back in a few minutes. Awesome

Comment: hi there dear Timeless - i have added your lines to the code - See the threadstart and how the code looks like now. dear Timeless:  i am so happy about your posting.

Comment: well  many thanks - i have added the full code - that i runned after your solution. now i am facing the next  issue. 
now i need to find out how i can fix this